# What is the species name of this red berried tree from Stellenbosch, Cape Town

Tags: identification, berries

Please help with identifying this tree. I harvested berries from it and want to propagate it but only if it is indigenous to Cape Town, South Africa.

It was found on Stellenbosch University campus, is about 1-2 meters tall and growing against the wall. It has red berries

[image: tree shape]

[image: leaf and berry detail]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Nandina domestica, an evergreen or semi evergreen shrub - if your 'tree' has a thick trunk, then it isn't Nandina. Usual height is up to 8 feet, but I suspect this plant is pruned back  regularly to keep it against the wall, which would account for its being a little taller. Common name Heavenly Bamboo because of its tendency to grow upright, similar to bamboo, but it is not a bamboo at all.

It is not native to South Africa, originating from China, Japan and India.

Comment: Good job Bamboo!!